# WPF (Bug) FocusVisualStyle doesn't work for Window with Template

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have got the problem with **FocusVisualStyle**, I need to override **TAB keyboard** focus style, when i'm override **Window.Template** all controls styles **FocusVisualStyle** on the window stops working.

The problem XAML (Tab style doesn't work):

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="800"
    Height="450">
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonTabFocused" TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="-3" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="Red" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Button
            Width="100"
            Height="40"
            Content="MyButton"
            FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ButtonTabFocused}" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Without **Window.Style** **FocusVisualStyle** works well (Tab style works):

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="800"
    Height="450">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonTabFocused" TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="-3" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="Red" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Button
            Width="100"
            Height="40"
            Content="MyButton"
            FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ButtonTabFocused}" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

No msdn information founded. Could you please tell me any workarounds or am i missed something what's makes this behavior.

My environments:

- .NET Framework 4.7.2 (same for older versions)
- Windows 10 19042.685
- Visual Studio 2019

Thanks.

UPDATE, working style below, thanks to arxont:

```
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Grid>
                        <AdornerDecorator>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add AdornerDecorator. Change your window style:

```
<AdornerDecorator>
    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />                       
</AdornerDecorator>
```